# I can't get this variable from ViewModel

Tags: kotlin, variables, viewmodel

[image]

I can't find a solution.

I tried so many time but nothing.

```
class UpdateFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentUpdateBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val updateViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this)[UpdateViewModel::class.java]

        _binding = FragmentUpdateBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val textView: TextView = UpdateViewModel.text
        updateViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            textView.text = it

        }
        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Take out the `_` before `binding` on the offending line. Read the page about nullability in the Kotlin documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question.
But if you want to update the text view, you can just call using binding and get value from your view model

```
updateViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    binding.textView.text = it

}
```

And you don't need to create a text view, you can remove this line.

```
 val textView: TextView = UpdateViewModel.text
```

I hope I answered your question.